# Couple of beginner's questions

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

I've just imported my blog from blogger to WordPress and I am running into few issues.

1. How to automatically set featured images to 400+ posts. I mean I want the first image in the post to be featured image. Manually setting it is time-consuming. Any plugin?
2. How to remove the category/tag "Uncategorised"?
3. I have changed the permalinks format of posts from the default blogger to default WordPress but I'm using Smart 404 plugin which automatically redirects most of the old post address to the new address, will it impact SEO?
4. Staying with number 3, how can I make it all old links work again. (I put some script from wpbeginner in functions.php but it didn't seem to work).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check this: Check this: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-how-to-automatically-set-the-featured-image-in-wordpress/
2. http://dominiquej.com/how-to-delete-uncategorized-wordpress/
3. No, 301 redirects will typically not impact your performance in the SERPs negatively when done correctly.
4. Please specify your question.

Comment: Thanks! 4th question was the alternative of Smart 404 plugin which I think I don't need anymore. For the 1st point, I recommend the plugin mentioned in my post's first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1.: You can find a lot of plugins solving this request. wpbeginner posted an article touching this topic: 14 Best Featured Image Plugins and Tutorials for WordPress

Regarding 3./4.: Use the Redirection plugin to point each URL that causes an error to the new URL. You can find the plugin in the WordPress repository. The plugin will set proper 301-redirects